A question about snapping
I am trying to snap my this 3D model to this particular edge using snapping but when I try to do that. Not only does it only move the edge selected, it doesn't snap the two edges together, how can I make it so my entire object is moved and so that the edges are against each other ?



This is expected behavior.

Virtually any operation (including Move) will, by default, only run on the selected elements. Selection would be basically useless if it didn’t specify which elements an operation runs on.
It appears that the selected edge did indeed snap to the targeted edge. Snapping does not add rotation to a move operation by default, although I believe there is a setting to use the target’s orientation in the snap menu?

The one thing I’m not sure about from your screenshot is why it appears that the end of the edge is snapped to the target and not the center, I don’t think this is default behavior, but you could’ve set snapping to “closest“ instead of the default “center.”
Please see The Blender Manual for more information.
